# TypeNotPresentException on javax.annotations.Nonnull

Tags: java, maven, annotations

I have added maven surefire plugin (2.17) to our project, but the build fails with the following error.

```
Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type javax.annotation.Nonnull not present
    at com.ibm.oti.reflect.AnnotationHelper.getAnnotation(AnnotationHelper.java:39)
    at com.ibm.oti.reflect.AnnotationHelper.getDeclaredAnnotations(AnnotationHelper.java:51)
    at com.ibm.oti.reflect.Method.getDeclaredAnnotations(Method.java:35)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getDeclaredAnnotations(Method.java:719)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.getAnnotations(AccessibleObject.java:187)
    at com.ibm.oti.reflect.Method.getAnnotation(Method.java:21)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getAnnotation(Method.java:693)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getAtInject(InjectionPoint.java:478)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints(InjectionPoint.java:676)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields(InjectionPoint.java:366)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.getInternalDependencies(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:165)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalDependencies(InjectorImpl.java:609)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.cleanup(InjectorImpl.java:565)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding(InjectorImpl.java:551)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:865)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:790)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:278)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:210)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:986)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1019)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:982)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:55)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.onProvision(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:109)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:55)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:997)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1047)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:993)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:260)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:459)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:97)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.Nonnull
    at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at com.ibm.oti.reflect.AnnotationHelper.getAnnotation(AnnotationHelper.java:34)
```

I have added the following dependency thinking that may be JSR305 jar is missing, but still getting the same error.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Any idea on how to resolve this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known bug in the IBM JVM: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IZ76352

You can either upgrade to the latest IBM JVM, switch to an alternative JVM, or add jsr305 as a dependency to the surefire plugin (ie inside the plugin section, not as a dependency to the project).

Comment: Adding the dependency in the plugin section did it for me

Answer (score 3):

This issue took me much time as well. Now using below config, the build error does not display anymore.

...
...

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
                <forkCount>1</forkCount>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```